# What are the parameter of get_info in stem

Tags: stem

From [stem documentation](https://stem.torproject.org/api/control.html#stem.control.Controller.get_info), the syntax of `get_info` is

```
get_info(params, default = UNDEFINED, get_bytes = False)
```

Where can I find a list of possible GETINFO parameters
 `params`?